# Почему нужно сравнивать BYTE (unsigned char) со степенью 2 для нахождения значения конкретного бита?

Tags: c, битовые-операции

Есть несколько способов нахождения значения бита в Байте, я нашла некоторую функцию, которая представляет Байт и степень двойки в бинарном виде, сравнивает их.

Но у меня возникли вопросы :

1. Почему мы вообще сравниваем значение со степенью двойки?
2. Зачем мы раскладываем 2^8 ?
3. Почему если побитовое сравнение не равно 0, то это целый бит?

`B` - к примеру, 196 'Д'

```
int GetBitValue(unsigned char B, int N){
  int k = 256; 
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    k /= 2;

  if ((B & k) != 0)  
    return 1;
  else return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Почему мы вообще сравниваем значение со степенью двойки?

Потому, что если в числе установлен ровно один бит, то это число является степенью двойки

```
0000_0001b = 1d   = 20  
0000_0010b = 2d   = 21  
0000_0100b = 4d   = 22  
0000_1000b = 8d   = 23  
0001_0000b = 16d  = 24  
0010_0000b = 32d  = 25  
0100_0000b = 64d  = 26  
1000_0000b = 128d = 27
```

> Зачем мы раскладываем 2^8 ?

Больная фантазия автора кода

По его замыслу биты нумеруются с единицы и самый левый бит имеет номер 1. Число 256 = 1_0000_0000b при каждом делении на 2 будет смещать свою единицу вправо

```
256 / 21 = 128 = 1000_0000b  
256 / 22 = 64  = 0100_0000b  
256 / 23 = 32  = 0010_0000b  
256 / 24 = 16  = 0001_0000b  
256 / 25 = 8   = 0000_1000b  
256 / 26 = 4   = 0000_0100b  
256 / 27 = 2   = 0000_0010b  
256 / 28 = 1   = 0000_0001b
```

> Почему если побитовое сравнение не равно 0, то это целый бит?

По определению операции побитового И. Она сравнивает попарно биты каждого операнда и устанавливает соответствующий бит результата в 1 только в том случае, если оба бита из сравниваемой пары равны 1.

Соответственно, когда мы сравниваем входной аргумент с некоторым числом у которого установлен ровно один бит, то мы гарантировано сбросим все остальные биты числа, а значение проверяемого окажется в результате.

Пример для `GetBitValue(196, 5)`

```
k = 256 / 25 = 8 = 0000_1000b
B = 196 = 1100_0100b  
& B: 1100_0100b
  k: 0000_1000b
res: 0000_0000b = 0
```

Еще один пример для `GetBitValue(204, 5)`

```
k = 256 / 25 = 8 = 0000_1000b
B = 204 = 1100_1100b  
& B: 1100_1100b
  k: 0000_1000b
res: 0000_1000b != 0
```

---

P.S. Правильная функция

```
int GetBitValue(int B, int N) {
  int k = 1 << N;  // Сдвигаем 1 на N позиций влево
  return (B & k) != 0;  // проверяем бит
}
```

Биты считаются с нулевого считая с права

Answer (score 0):

**1.** В бинарном виде число, являющееся степенью двойки, имеет в себе один активный бит.

```
4 = 2^2 = 100b; 
1 = 2^0 = 01b; 
64 = 2^6 = 1000000b;
```

Знак '&' в данном случае имеет значение "AND". Когда мы применяем операцию "AND" для любого числа (a) и числа, являющегося степенью двойки, (b) мы в результате получаем число, в бинарном представлении которого все биты, кроме одного, будет равно нулю. Значение оставшегося бита будет скопировано из 'a'.

```
  11111111b = 255
  AND
  00000010b = 4 = 2^2 <br/>
= 00000010b = 4
<br/>
```

**2.** В данном случае мы не раскладываем число 2^8, а сдвигаем все его биты вправо. Таким образом создатель данной процедуры добивается того, чтобы был активирован только нужный ему бит.
**3.** Потому что в результате "AND" операции между любым числом и степенью двойки возможны два результата:
а) (Искомый бит активен) Мы получаем число, все биты которого, кроме одного, равны 0. 
б) (Искомый бит неактивен) Мы получаем число, все биты которого равны нулю. Следовательно, число равно 0.

Кстати, в Assembly существует инструкция [BT](http://asmworld.ru/spravochnik-komand/bt/), которая определяет значение нужного бита. Если Вы пользуетесь C++, то можете попробовать использовать её.